# Downstairs bubbling toilet when upstairs shower runs

Tags: plumbing, shower, toilet, septic

What could cause the downstairs toilet in the middle of the house to bubble (and sometimes make the water disappear) when someone takes a shower upstairs all the way at the far side of the house?

Info - 2004 house w/septic (not full)

Comment: Sounds like vent/s is blocked.  Does this happen only with use of the shower, or with other fixtures also?

Answer (score 1):

That's a venting problem - either clogged vents, (inclusive of stuck mechanical vents and pipe type vents with obstructions) or built wrong in the first place with inadequate venting.

Comment: Thank you. That is what my research has come up with too. I can't find a plumber who fixes that. They want to snake my toilet.